# Nodejs&gulp fs.readdirSync cause "no such file or directory"

Tags: node.js, gulp

`fs.readdirSync` cause `no such file or directory`error for gulp.dest file.

I'm using `gulp.dest` to output file to local(like .tmp/myfolder/1.html), but in the next task, I try to read `myfolder`, it cause this error. The folder was already created, but why failed to read it ?

And after the process finished, I write a test task to read the folder using `fs.readdirSync`, it works well....

This problem happends on my dev linux server, but my local works well, so is it caused by `nodejs version`? Or anyother reason?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the folder exists on the server? And if so do you have permissions to read it? Does it work hardcoded? i.e. fs.readdirSync('.tmp/serve/forum')?

Comment: Yes, it exists. So no permission issue, and after the process, I run `gulp test`, show the file list. I tried hardcode, still not work.